# Meaning of the word "cru"

Tags: vocabulaire

I was reading *Le monde* when I encountered a passage I didn't understand.

> La fréquentation touristique a atteint un record « absolu » pour Paris et l’Ile-de-France au premier semestre grâce aux clientèles étrangères, même si l’essor de visiteurs en provenance de Chine et du Japon faiblit. « Après une année 2017 déjà exceptionnelle, **le cru** touristique 2018 est parti pour battre tous les records », a indiqué lundi 27 août le comité régional du tourisme (CRT) Paris Ile-de-France lors d’une conférence de presse au château de Versailles.

What does the word "cru" mean in this context? The dictionary isn't helping. Neither "raw" nor "vineyard" make sense in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il s'agit d'une métaphore très large en prenant le mot cru dans son sens premier comme millésime dans le domaine de la production viticole; un cru possède des caractéristiques uniques quant à la qualité du vin qui va par cette identification: on dit par exemple « un cru 2013 », « le cru 2014 Château Gombert », but you probably know all that. I leave the rest to your imagination.

Comment: *Château-Gombert ! Peuchère, y'en a plus des vignes depuis l'an pèbre là-haut...*

Comment: L'an pèbre... une éternité depuis que j'ai entendu celui-ci la dernière fois!@jlliagre

Comment: Étonnamment, à *Castèu-Goumbert*, les vignes ont commencé à être supplantées par d'autres cultures à partir de 1848, arrivée du Canal de Provence à Marseille, et 1848 est précisément aussi l'année qui correspond à l'*an pèbre*...

Comment: C'est en effet un lieu-dit dans le 13 ième arrondissement de la ville de Marseille et il ne doit pas se trouver de trop grandes parcelles de vignes dans un tel endroit; mais, peut-être pas une aussi massive révélation que celle de la fabuleuse sardine et certainement plus vrai, voilà plus fort: il y aurait dans le centre ville de Marseille à 100 mètres du Vieux Port, une parcelle de vigne.https://madeinmarseille.net/1407-vigne-centre-ville-marseille-agriculture/